# Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 192.168.99.100:8443: getsockopt: no route to host

Tags: kubernetes

Here is my YAML file :

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: tomcat-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: tomcat
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: tomcat
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: tomcat
        image: tomcat:9.0
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
```

When I run the command `kubectl apply -f ./deployment.yaml`, I got the following error : `Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 192.168.99.100:8443: getsockopt: no route to host`.

How can I fix that problem?

With `kubectl version`, it got Client Version:

```
version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"10", GitVersion:"v1.10.3", GitCommit:"2bba0127d85d5a46ab4b778548be28623b32d0b0", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-05-21T09:17:39Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Comment: Does `kubectl cluster-info` produce same output? Also, please post your kubernetes version and setup.

Comment: Yes, it does the same thing with `kubectl cluster-info`.

Comment: It sounds like you have a stale `current-context:` entry in your `~/.kube/config`; can you post the output of `kubectl config get-contexts` (and/or `kubectl config view`)?

Comment: This also happens for me on Mac OS with the latest minikube version (30). Viewing the VM I don't see any port mapping for 8443 which I would have expected. Perhaps you can post the default working config file here so we can try that?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to `curl https://192.168.99.100:8443`.

If port `8443` is open you should get something related to the certificate like:

```
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

If it's not open - make sure you expose it outside.